# Round one column up and another column down

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns, each with the same decimal value.

```
id  number1 number2
1   13.220  13.220
2   5.660   5.660
3   9.512   9.423
```

I want to round down number1 and round up number2 and return the results in one table. So far have this query:

```
select ceiling(number1) number1 from decimals
union
select FLOOR(number2) number2 from decimals;
```

It only combines both results into one column, and I want it to return two columns.

Comment: `select ceiling(number1) number1, floor(number2) number2 from decimals;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use both functions in single `SELECT` statement ? `UNION` set is unnecessary :

```
select ceiling(number1) number1, FLOOR(number2) number2  
from decimals;
```